# Rake Error while trying to run `rake db:create` in project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm new to Ruby and using RubyMine environment.
i'm using sqlite3.

when i try to create db - `rake db:create` i am getting the following error:

> rake aborted!
>
> no such file to load -- bundler/setup
>
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

please help me :)

i'm using ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5 and RVM on mac osx

Comment: do you have bundler gem installed?

Comment: run `gem list -d bundler` to see if you have bunder installed.

Comment: i getting this output:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: If you are running under RVM, don't use 'sudo'. A simple gem install bundler should suffice.